# strcat function how to use

Tags: c, strcat

I am pretty new in C language. I am trying to use strcat, the following example works:

```
  char s1[20] = "Happy ";
  char s2[15] = "world";
  char s3[40] = "";
  strcat(s3,s1);
```

Although, i wanted to practise a bit the pointers i have seen earlier, so:

```
char *s1 = "Happy";
char *s2 = "World";

strcat(*s2,*s1);
```

produces  argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *. Again, this might be easy, but be as clarifying as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example,

```
strcat(*s2,*s1);
```

has a type mismatch problem, as `*s2` and `*s1` are of type `char`. If you use:

```
strcat(s2,s1);
```

It would still be wrong, because `s2` points to a string literal, which can't be modified.

Comment: wait.. why s2 can't be modified?

Comment: @iol Modifying a **string literal** is undefined behavior.

Comment: It depends on how the `s2` is declared. If it's a string, as in your second sample, then yes, it can not be modified. But if it's a character array placed on the stack as in your first sample, it you may edit it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcat(*s2, *s1);
```

tries to concatenate two 8-bit characters instead of two strings, which is practically impossible. Strcat requires two pointers to strings. What it does is that it finds the end of the first string, and starts moving the second one character by character so the result is a one longer string.

It is declared as

```
char * strcat (char * destination, const char * source);
```

and therefore

```
char s1[20] = "Hello ";
char s2[40] = "World!";
strcat(s2, s1);
```

is the way to go, because both `s2` and `s1` are pointers.

However, if you really wanted to play with pointers, you could use

```
char* strs[2];
strs[0] = "Hello ";
strs[1] = "World!";

char res[20];
strcat(res, *strs);
strcat(res, strs[1]);
```

Comment: I tried that but i get Access violation writing location 0x0118CC78,

Comment: @iol On which one? I may have made a mistake. Also, I made a minor edit, have a look.

Comment: ok this works if you initialize char res[20] = " ". Though what i wanted to do is to strcat(strs[0],strs[1]) which does not seem to work

Comment: Never mind **my fault**, i read the above comments again and it seems like you cannot change the value of string literal so i guess that is why i cannot do an strcat(strs[0],strs[1]);

Comment: Yes, that's it. Is it OK now?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are having difficulties, is because you are dereferencing the first character in `s2` and `s1` by using `*` in front of `s2` and `s1`. Here is why.

Although an array of characters is not considered exactly the same type as a pointer to one or more characters, the array name, let's take `s1` as an example, is considered a pointer to the first character in the array `s`, which is `'H'`. Using the name `s2` points to the first character in s2, which is `'w'`. Therefore if putting an asterisk in front of `s2` or `s1`, results in reading the first character in each of those arrays, respectively.

So, as has been pointed out in another answer, you are trying to concatenate two 8-bit characters, not concatenating one string to the end of the other.